# I want to create a table in SQL of column of current date, current month_name etc

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

if today date is 12/14/2023 then i want a table in SQL of columns like Month_name , Year_name, day. Acc to this example `Month_name= "December", Year_name = 2023`

I want the data which is the current_month, current_date,current_year if today i run the script it should be 14 date tomorrow it should be 15. It should change dynamically.

Comment: What is your question? Have you looked into both (1) CTAS statement, and; (2) Working with dates in Snowflake?

Comment: You want the columns in the table to literally be `month_name` and `year_name` or you want them to literally be `December` and `2023`? If the former, what part of this are you stuck on? Create the table and insert data into it. If the latter, yuck, why?

Comment: You would just wrap a CTAS around `select 
 monthname(current_date) as month_name, 
 TO_CHAR((CURRENT_DATE),'MMMM') as full_month_name, 
 year(current_date) as year_name`

Comment: But if you plan to Insert other data into that table, then define each column type as well during the CTAS. Cast to appropriate data type (ie, char vs varchar vs ....).

Comment: if Snowflake is the database, then `text` `varchar` `char` are all the same type, so no need to type the string, and the size limit is only of use if you want truncation, and explosion's when you later try insert more data, the default 16MB (and upper limit) is optimal otherwise (because the data is immutable, strings are just what they are),

Comment: I want the data which is the current_month, current_date,current_year if today i run the script it should be 14 date tomorrow it should be 15.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
select date_part(MONTH,current_date()) month
     , current_date() date
     , date_part(YEAR,current_date()) year ;
```